# How do I design a flexible MySQL notification schema that references multiple tables?

Tags: php, mysql, notifications, schema

I decided to work on a notification system with inspiration from another StackOverflow post that suggested I break up the notification from the body of the notification. As such, I have the following schema:

```
notifications
id | user_id | notification_object_id | is_read

notification_objects
id | message | type
```

I have it set up this way so I can create a notification object and send this out to multiple users in the case the notification object applies to multiple people. The type is there to condense messages into one notification by type, sort of the way Facebook says, "John Doe, John Smith, and 27 other users commented..." rather than giving you 29 separate notifications.

(The naming schema of the table and column are for CakePHP 3's 'contains')

What I need help on is a way to tie in the different users or objects that would be playing a role in the requests. A user might have commented, so I'll probably need the user_id of the user who messaged and need to store that somewhere.

There are other cases besides users; one might want to know the id of the comment such that he can click the notification and go straight to comment/81. I have many use cases where I want to store the different types of ids that are foreign keys to other tables (users, comments, articles, etc.), some of which might need two foreign keys (say you want to mention "[Chris](http://#) has commented on your [article](http://#) 'How to beg StackOverflow for help'") and have the user_id for Chris and the article id for the article both linked in the notification.

Each different type of notification could have different values and tables it needs to pull information from. What's a good place to start on creating this schema?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm going to try and answer this question from an OO perspective. When speaking in *classes*, not in *tables*, you'd probably start with something like an `AbstractNotificationObject` class with the basic properties (date, time, maybe a message) and several specialization classes like `NewCommentNotificationObject` with additional properties (comment, commenting user) or a `NewFriendNotificationObject`. Going down to the database schema, you could then apply one of the typical ORM patterns.

#### Concrete table inheritance (just for completeness)

Using *[concrete table inhericance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html)* would probably not be a good idea, because it would boil down to a **separate table for each notification type** (i.e. a `comment_notification_objects` table and maybe many more). This would not scale well, and you would not be able to reference them from the `notification` table using a foreign key. Also, you would not be able to select a set of notifications of different types with a single query (without something like a UNION).

#### Single table inheritance

*[Single table inheritance](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html)* would use only a **single table with a type discriminator column**. This single table (let's call it `notification_objects`) would need to contain a `type` column that describes of what type of notification the record actually is (you actually already have that in your schema). You'll also need columns for all properties that special notification types may have (for instance, a `user_id` and a `comment_id` column).

```
   +--------------+
   | notification |
   +--------------+
   | id           |
+--| object_id    |
|  +--------------+
|
|  +-----------------------+
|  | notification_objects  |
|  +-----------------------+
+->| id PK                 |
   | date                  |
   | type                  |
   | user_id FK            |--...
   | comment_id FK         |--...
   | friend_id FK          |--...
   | [more fields to come] |
   +-----------------------+
```

**Pros**:

1. Load all notifications with a single query
2. Keep referential integrity with foreign keys

**Cons**:

1. Scales badly (you'll need to add new columns for each notification type)
2. Table will be sparsely populated (many columns will be NULL)

**I would recommend this schema when you have a set of notification types of moderate size that does not regularly change**.

#### Class table inheritance

*[Class table inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html)* is somewhere in between; here you would create a central `notification_objects` table and separate tables for each notification type (for example an additional `comment_notification_object` table with an `id` column (which in turn is a foreign key to the `notification_object` table and a `user_id` and `column_id`:

```
   +--------------+
   | notification |
   +--------------+
   | id           |
+--| object_id    |
|  +--------------+
|
|  +----------------------+      +------------------------------+
|  | notification_objects |      | comment_notification_objects |
|  +----------------------+      +------------------------------+
+->| id PK                |<--+--| id PK/FK                     |
   | date                 |   |  | comment_id FK                |--...
   | type                 |   |  | user_id FK                   |--...
   +----------------------+   |  +------------------------------+
                              |
                              |  +--------------------------------+
                              |  | newfriend_notification_objects |
                              |  +--------------------------------+
                              +--| id PK/FK                       |
                                 | friend_id FK                   |--...
                                 +--------------------------------+

                                 [more TABLES to come...]
```

Class table inheritance would also allow you to query all notifications with a single select query. Depending on how much of the data you need, you'll need to add JOINs to the respective specialized tables.

**Pros**:

1. Scales well/Add new types without modifying existing structure
2. Keep referential integrity with foreign keys

**Cons**:

1. When you need more than the minimal set of fields, you'll need to JOIN the specialized tables (possible performance impact)

**I would recommend this schema when you have a lot of different notification types or extend your object model often and need to change/add new notification types on a regular basis.**

#### Outside the relational box

Your question asked explicitly about relational schema, so I've focused on that. When thinking outside this box, alternate solutions might include:

- Schemaless NoSQL databases
- Messaging systems that follow a publish/subscribe architecture

Comment: Amazing, in-depth answer. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @helmbert can you please describe more for NoSQL database

Comment: @Xyroid This question was explicitly about relational databases; going into detail on non-relational databases would go widely outside the scope of the original question. Feel free to ask this as a new question (clearly stating which of the numerous different NoSQL databases you are referring to).